# How can I assign element count to the variable?

Tags: cypress

I get element with class and find its children. I need to get count of children element and assigned to variable `currentCount`.

```js
let curentCount = cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
                    .first()
                    .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
                    .its('length')
cy.log(curentCount)
```

After there I make some actions and need to compare element counts in the end.

```js
cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', curentCount)
cy.log(curentCount)
```

But I usually received:

```js
Object: {5}
```

And I cannot compare these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Cypress works is to pass values down the chain, but when you try to get `let curentCount =...` it gives you a Chainer object.

How about saving to an alias

```js
cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
  .its('length')
  .as('initialCount')

// do your actions

cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
  .its('length')
  .as('nextCount')

// compare
cy.get('@initialCount').then(initial => {
  cy.get('@nextCount'). then(next => {
    expect(initial).to.eq(next)
  })
})
```

It still works the way you had it, but be aware that the variable is a Chainer and value must be accessed in a chain,

```js
const currentCountChainer = cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
  .its('length')

// do your actions

cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
  .its('length')
  .then(nextCount => {
    currentCountChainer.should('eq', nextCount)   // carry on the previous chain
  })
```

This is not so conventional, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

For saving the count

```
cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
    .first()
    .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
    .its('length')
    .as('count')
```

To validate the count -

```
cy.get('@count').then((count) => {
    cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
        .first()
        .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
        .its('length')
        .should('eq', count)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This example work fine for me :

```
    // 'input' is the element that I want count
    cy.get('input').then(($cnt) => {
      const count = $cnt.length;
      console.log(count);

      // put the rest of the code here

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `curentCount` is a Cypress object that represents the length of the children elements. To get the *actual* value of `curentCount`, you need to use the `.then()` method to extract the value from the Cypress object.

Here's an updated code snippet that should work:

```
let curentCount
cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
  .its('length')
  .then((length) => {
    curentCount = length
    cy.log(curentCount)
  })

// Later in your code...

cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', curentCount)
  .then((length) => {
    cy.log(length)
  })
```

This code sets `curentCount` by extracting the *length* value from the Cypress object using `.then()`. Then, later in the code, it compares the length of the children elements to curentCount and logs the length value.